# MDI Form issue VB:NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, mdi

Hy today i have some problems with the Panel Control and MDI Child Forms, My problem is that I can not set the panel control to back of child forms.
My head is spinning trying to solve this problem.

[image: MDI Client Z-Order Problem]

Comment: You'll have to do this differently.  Put the buttons in a panel, dock the panel to one of the edges of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you added your Panel to your ParentForm, doing so will keep on top. You need to Assign it to a ChildForm. One of your other options would be to create a dockable panel and dock it on the side of your parent.

Take a look at these articles

1. http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/382474-how-do-you-bring-mdi-child-windows-front-if-mdi-parent-has-controls
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winforms/thread/a9682277-d612-41e8-b5c0-44434b0bcb22

---

Based on your comment you can do something like this with a Timer set for 100ms

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Panel1.Visible = CheckForMDIChildren()
End Sub

Private Function CheckForMDIChildren() As Boolean
    If Me.MdiChildren.Count > 0 Then
        For Each frm As Form In Me.MdiChildren
            If frm.Visible Then Return False
        Next
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: That's right, but I need this set to back panel of MDI children, as it is a quick shortcut panel.

Comment: It will always be on top, I am looking for the reference. I think your only option will be to set the visibility

Comment: I'm afraid to have to schedule everything an algorithm to hide and show the panel each time a form is active.