# Child form is hidden in the main form

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a main form and a childform. 
On the main form, I have a button. When I click that button, it displays the childform without any problem. This is the code from the button:

```
frmClient.MdiParent = Me
frmClient.Show()
```

The problem is that frmClient is displayed at the back of the controls from the Main Form.
Here is the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Adding

```
frmClient.BringToFront()
```

does not solve the problem.

Is this how childforms behave and displayed? If not, how can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like this is a Mdi application and you have controls on the main form, Any controls on the main form will be above your child forms. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12889849/479512

Comment: Okay, thank you so much mark. Now it is clear to me that this is really how mdi behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Call BringToFront function before show the child form and then try it.

```
client.BringToFront();//This will make your child form shown on top.
childForm.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks, I stated it on the problem but still it's not working

Comment: // Display the form as top most form.
childFrom.TopMost = true;